# How to use CORS with .NET6 minimal APIs?

Tags: c#, heroku, cors, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I have a .NET6 minimal api deployed in Heroku that is returning this following CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin '...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

But the same configuration is not returning any errors when I run my app locally.

```
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MyAllowedOrigins",
        policy =>
        {
            policy
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});
```

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("MyAllowedOrigins");

app.MapPost("/upload-file", async ([FromServices] IWordService service, HttpRequest request) =>...
```

Comment: Try to restart your heroku dyno, your code should work.

Comment: I restarted it but I'm getting the same error. Maybe it is the order that I added the CORS?

Comment: i've tried that on my machine, and it works in every combination

Comment: What is the output of `curl -H "Origin: https://example.com" --verbose \
  https://example.com`

Comment: Trying 54.159.116.102:443...
Connected to exam-grader-api.herokuapp.com (54.159.116.102) port 443 (#0)
schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
ALPN: offers http/1.1
ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
GET /get-students?level=PET&year= HTTP/1.1
Host: exam-grader-api.herokuapp.com
User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
Accept: */*
Origin: https://exam-grader-web.herokuapp.com/
Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 02 Oct 2022 10:46:20 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Via: 1.1 vegur

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to **Enable Cors with endpoint routing**. See this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#enable-cors-with-endpoint-routing

Check your **Middleware order**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: You should not do this. It is not a safe way. Do it only if you don't care.

The following is middleware for Minimal API. It effectively bypasses CORS by giving him what he wants:

```cs
//f**k you CORS
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;

        await WriteCorsAsync(context);

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("");
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.OnStarting(WriteCorsAsync, context);

        await next(context);
    }

    static Task WriteCorsAsync(object state)
    {
        var context = (HttpContext)state;

        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", context.Request.Headers.Origin);
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", string.Join(", ", new[] { context.Request.Method }.Union(context.Request.Headers.AccessControlRequestMethod.Select(v => v))));
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", string.Join(", ", context.Request.Headers.Select(p => p.Key).Union(context.Request.Headers.AccessControlRequestHeaders.Select(v => v))));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
});
```